# how to annotate DTO to enable case-insensitive mapping?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-table-storage

**How do I read data into a concrete model without knowing the case of the source column names?**

I'm reading data out of table storage:

```
public static IEnumerable<Translation> GetTranslations(string sourceParty, string destinationParty)
{
    var acc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RRRCacheStorageConnection"));
    var tableClient = acc.CreateCloudTableClient();
    var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RRRTableCache"));

    TableQuery<Translation> rangeQuery = new TableQuery<Translation>().Where(
        TableQuery.CombineFilters(
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SourcePartyColumnName"), QueryComparisons.Equal, sourceParty),
            TableOperators.And,
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DestinationPartyColumnName"), QueryComparisons.Equal, destinationParty)));

    return table.ExecuteQuery(rangeQuery);
}
```

Then I dump into a concrete model, which looks like this:

```
public class Translation : TableEntity
{
    public Translation()
    {

    }
    public string translatefrom { get; set; }
    public string translateto { get; set; }
    public string TranslationId { get; set; }
    public string FieldType { get; set; }
    public string sourceparty { get; set; }
    public string destinationparty { get; set; }
}
```

However, if the source table in Azure has a field called TranslateFrom and not translatefrom (as defined in the class above), then data is not read.

**How do I read data into a concrete model without knowing the case of the source column names?**

Comment: This absolutely can be done; however I'm not super familiar with table storage. When I .AddSignalR (AzureSignalR) I do this in startup to get around it - so it *can* be done.. You'll need to wait on someone with experience for table storage to answer though if this doesn't point you to it:
.AddAzureSignalR(signalRConnString)
           .AddJsonProtocol(options =>
           {
               options.PayloadSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
           });

Answer (score 1):

You should follow conventions of `UpperCamelCase` in C# and `lowerCamelCase` for JSON/JS

So mixing conventions like you have it is a bad idea and will just cause problems with libraries like Entity, causes problems for other users on the readability side and once you start doing API calls gets completely confusing.

Update your table entity to use all `UpperCamelCase`. The same applies for DTO's because JSON Convert will automatically apply `lowerCamelCase` during serialisation and deserialazation for JavaScript while keeping your code within the C# Convention.

There is an option to tell Entity to ignore casing... but I rather provide you with an outside opinion to NOT change the conventions that where put in place by clever people... but rather fix your approach to make life easier for everyon down the line.

Assuming this standard way of writing C# (UpperCase)

```
public class TestClass {
   public string TranslateFrom { get; set; }
}
```

and you return it via your ActionResult in MVC or API

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod() {
  return Json(new TestClass(){TranslateFrom="z-axis"});
}
```

the JSON (property naming convention) will be lowerCase

```
{ "translateFrom" : "z-axis" }
```

and the other way around. You can send upper or lower case to C# MVC/API and Newtonsoft.JSON will work out. But you should stick with JavaScript convention of always lowerCase properties.

Your class should look like this.

```
public class Translation : TableEntity
{
    public string TranslateFrom { get; set; }
    public string TranslateTo { get; set; }
    public string TranslationId { get; set; }
    public string FieldType { get; set; }
    public string SourceParty { get; set; }
    public string DestinationParty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: *There is an option to tell Entity to ignore casing* -- how do we do this?

Comment: *JSON Convert will automatically apply lowerCamelCase during serialisation and deserialazation for JavaScript while keeping your code within the C# Convention.* - you are saying JSON has a built-in engine that can take any cased-string and convert it to camelcase?

Comment: Newtonsoft.JSON applies these conventions for Javascript purposes. If your DTO is UpperCamelCase the serialisation comes out lowerCamelCase to comply with say TypeScript Linting! JSON is a WebStandard where they always did lowerCamelCase and C# is C# and its always been UpperCamelCase

Comment: I wont tell you how to change the convention.. because I am trying to tell you NOT to do it. You just making things worse

Comment: beautiful. so you are recommending that i update the table column names (stored in table api) to be camelCase, right?  that way, when we deserialize to c# class, it will automatically map `camelCase` to `CamelCase` ?

Comment: Yes. By choosing C# and EntityFramework you go into this agreement that this is the convetion you will use. So the SQL table names, column names will all be UpperCamelCase because of C# conventions. And C# will properly output it to lowerCamelCase for JavaScript as per THEIR convention. Everybody is happy. :D

Comment: i'm not using EF, how come you made that assumption?

Comment: it seems like you may have misunderstood me and this answer is awesome but it's geared towards EF-approach, which is not my path of choice for the above question

Comment: Oh right. Sorry just similar similar to EF it has changed so much recently. Doens't matter.. the convention still applies.